# Displacement is different from object to render mode

Tags: rendering, displacement

I have a slight problem that never showed on blender2.7. And I'm brand new on Blender 2.9.
When in object mode, my cube touches the surface with a displacement modifier but in render mode and when I render this cube hovers over the surface.
Why is the plane suddenly sinking? And how can I bring it back to level Z0?
Thanks in advance for tips!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a displacement on the plane shader too ?

Comment: Indeed I had one, so dumb I didn't realize it could alterate  that much... ^^' I changed it and it's back to normal. Thanks for the advice!